# Sakurai's approach to $\hat p$ as the generator of translations

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Often times one simply postulates that the momentum operator is the generator of translations or follows [the reasoning here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/45067/), for example.  I am working through Sakurai and Napolitano's Modern Quantum Mechanics 3rd Ed, and below is the part I want clarified (copied from 2nd Ed.)  When he says, "We are led to speculate," I do not see why.  The two expressions

$$  \vec x\cdot\vec P,~~\quad\text{and}\qquad  1-i\hat{\vec K}\cdot d\vec x ~~,$$

seem quite different to me.  I can look at these two expressions and, without the suggestion in the book, I am not drawn to speculate in this manner.  What connection suggests this speculation?

[image]

Comment: Linked:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/554626/how-translation-operator-is-defined  ,   https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/533256/quantum-mechanics-sakurai-infinitesimal-translation     , https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/318497/spatial-translations-in-qm-as-described-in-sakurai  .

Comment: Thanks.  I take it as a good sign when my question about a passage in book has been asked before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect what is confusing you is the apparent typo in (1.6.29) where the **p** is supposed to be **P** to yield the first of the equations (1.6.28): it is a type 2 generating function, after all, *F*(**x,P**), with ${\mathbf X}=\partial F/\partial {\mathbf P}$, in our case $= {\mathbf x} +d {\mathbf x} $. So, as he reminds you, *F* is a machine consisting of the identity  plus a piece that ads a small increment $d {\mathbf x} $ to ${\mathbf x}$ and nobody else, as ${\mathbf P}=\partial F/\partial {\mathbf x}={\mathbf p}$, so, basically, a gradient w.r.t. **x**.

This is meant to evoke the standard linear QM [shift operator of Lagrange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_operator), a mere rewriting of Taylor's series around the constant d**x**,
$$
e^{id{\mathbf x}\cdot {\mathbf K}}f({\mathbf x})= f({\mathbf x}+d{\mathbf x})\\  \approx ( I +id{\mathbf x}\cdot {\mathbf K} )f({\mathbf x}) = f({\mathbf x})+ d{\mathbf x}\cdot \partial f/\partial {\mathbf x},
$$
the increment term also involving a gradient.

The evocation and the name are not that necessary, really; if you were a Martian, the commutation relations of **K** with **x** dictating representation thereof with a gradient $-i\nabla$ would tell you everything you need. But the two S's remind you that you should expect to observe this shadow-dance between QM and classical mechanics, and **K** should strongly evoke the classical phase-space variable **p**, so it's good mental hygiene to call it momentum.

The minus sign you have is because S defines his translation on kets, which transform with a minus sign w.r.t. bras, and functions are basically bras, $f(x) =\langle x | f\rangle$. I could have done the whole thing with the minus sign and the kets, without reminding you that you are *really* discussing a bland Lagrange shift, in pompous language,  after all.